# Exponential map and convexity (Riemannian geometry)

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry

Let $M$ be a complete Riemannian manifold, and let $x,p\in M$ be two points.

Consider the exponential map $\exp_x:T_xM\to M$, suppose that we are given  $X,Y\in T_xM$
$$d_ M(\exp_x(X), p)<\varepsilon, \quad d_ M(\exp_x(Y), p)<\varepsilon, $$
holds (here $d_M:M\times M\to \mathbb{R}$ is the distance function on $M$).
We can also suppose that $||X||, ||Y||<\rho_x$ where $\rho_x$ is the injectivity radius at $x$.

> Is it true that for all $t\in[0,1], $ we have that $d_ M(\exp_x(tX+(1-t)Y), p)<\varepsilon$? In other words, the preimage of the ball $B_{d_M}(p,\varepsilon)$ under $\exp_x$ is convex in $T_x M$?

I am reading a paper where the author seems to implicitely assume this.
However I do not know anything about the behaviour of the exponential map with respect to the vector space structure of $T_xM$.

**Edit**
Notice that we are interested in $\exp_x$ restricted to the ball of radius $\rho_x$ in $T_xM$ as above, not defined over the whole $T_xM$.

Comment: You may be looking for the notion of *convexity radius*. Here is a [related post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1213366/lower-bound-on-convexity-radius-in-terms-of-injectivity-radius-without-using-cu).

Comment: @Didier thank you for your comment.  I am more interested about how that notion of convexity relates to this one. The two notions are different.

Comment: The preimage $\exp_x^{-1}(B_{d_M}(x,\varepsilon))$ need not even be connected. For instance, on the flat torus $\mathbb{R}^2/\mathbb{Z}^2$, the preimage $\exp_x^{-1}(B_{d_M}(x,\varepsilon))$ consists of infinitely many disjoint discs when $\varepsilon\le 1/2$.

Comment: @Kajelad thank you for the interest, however your example does not completely answer the question, indeed as you can read in the premise we supposed that $||X||$ and $||Y||$ are smaller than the injectivity radius therefore in the case of tori the assertion is true (only one of the disks you mentioned will bee considered).

Comment: @WarlockofFiretopMountain Right. Still, your "in other words" isn't quite equivalent, it looks to me like you're instead asking if $\exp_x^{-1}(B(p,\varepsilon))\cap B(0,\rho_x)$ is convex. This is also false without additional assumptions: let $M$ be the unit sphere, chose $x$ and $p$ to be antipodal, and let $\epsilon<\pi$, and the resulting subset is an annulus. It might be useful to cite/link the paper in which the assertion appears for additional context.

Comment: @Kajelad thank you, you are right about the equivalence (I tried to summarize the question but I forgot to add that constraint) and this  answers my question completely. I will ask another question today or tomorrow mentioning exactly the proof that is giving me troubles. Please feel free to post your comment as an answer, if you like, I will accept it.

Comment: @Kajelad please take a look at my follow up question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4412746/showing-that-exp-y-2-1-circ-exp-y-1-is-convex-exponential-map-of-ri?noredirect=1&lq=1