# Geodesically convexity and convexity in normal coordinates

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry, global-analysis

This question regards an assertion in the proof of Theorem 1.3.1 of Douglas Moore's book "Introduction to Global Analysis, Minimal Surfaces in Riemannian Manifolds" (AMS, 2017).

**Assumptions/Definitions:**

$M$ is a *complete*, compact Riemannian manifold $M$. Consider $y_1, y_2 \in M$  two points, $\varepsilon_i>0$, $i=1,2.$

Set  $D_i := \{v \in T_{y_i}M | \ |v|< \varepsilon_i\} $, and $B_i := \{z\in M \ | d_M(z,y_i) < \varepsilon_i\}$.

We suppose that:

1. the exponential map gives **diffeomorphisms**
   $$\exp_{y_i}|_{D_i}:D_i\to B_i$$
2. $B_1, B_2, $ and $B_1\cap B_2$ are **geodesically convex** (i.e. any two points can be joined by a unique minimizing geodesic)

**Problem**

At page 20 of the book there is a claim about convexity which I don't know how to prove, let me state it precisely.

We would like to show that the domain  $U$ where the composition
$ (\exp_{y_2}|_{D_2})^{-1}\circ \exp_{y_1}|_{D_1}$
is defined  is **convex** in $T_{y_1}M$.
Notice that $$U := \exp_{y_1}^{-1} (B_2)\cap D_1$$

> Question: why  is $U$ convex?

My initial idea was to show a property which turned out to be false, as showed by @Kajelad on
[Exponential map and convexity (Riemannian geometry)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4410836/exponential-map-and-convexity-riemannian-geometry?noredirect=1#comment9228934_4410836)
that is why I decided to add the geodetically convex hypothesis.

We know that $B_1\cap B_2$ is geodetically convex, is not clear how this implies that the preimage of it under the exponential map at $y_1$ is convex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even with the added requirement of geodesic convexity, this is false. A similar counterexample is to let $M$ be the unit sphere and choose $\varepsilon_1=\varepsilon_2=\pi/2$. This will always satisfy the convexity requirements, and if $y_1$ and $y_2$ are chosen sufficiently close to antipodal, the resulting $U$ will be a nonconvex "half-crescent" shape.

Glancing at the cited book, the discussion of convexity don't seem to make sense. Unless I'm mistaken, it can be disregarded entirely with a slight change in argument: Fiberwise convexity is only needed in order for the Taylor remainder integral to be well-defined, but even without it, the integral will be well-defined locally (due to compactness), which suffices for the local computations in the proof.

Comment: How can I see that $U$ has this "half-crescent" shape?

Comment: @WarlockofFiretopMountain It might be useful to draw a picture. When $y_1,y_2$ are antipodal, $B_1$ and $B_2$ will be disjoint hemispheres and $\partial B_1=\partial B_2$ will be a great circle. Shifting $y_1$ and $y_2$ slightly toward each other will cause the two hemispheres to overlap along a "sliver" covering half of this great circle.